# How to style img in print layout html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I am new to web development and I am trying to create a function that prints a web page. All works properly but I'm having some difficulties with styling images. I had already styled other things with media queries, hiding unnecessary divs and items but I have some difficulties with images that have inline style `width: 100%`.

I attach my code below:

**Javascript**

```
$('#print-btn-page').click(function(){  
   alert('pagina');
   var url_popup = '<?php echo $page_link?>';
   console.log(url_popup);
   var pagina = window.open(url_popup);
   setTimeout(function () { pagina.print(); }, 500);
   pagina.onfocus = function () { setTimeout(function () { pagina.close(); }, 500); }   
});
```

**CSS print style (at the end of style.css)**

```
/* Print Style */
@media print {
   a[href]:after {
       content: none !important;
   }
   .icam-top-footer{display:none}
   .icam-bottom-footer{display:none}
   .icam-bottom-footer-mobile{display:none}
   .icam-page-submenu{display:none}
   .icam-main-menu{display:none}
   .icam-menu-sidebar{display:none}
   .icam-logo-print{display: none}
   .icam-page-prodotti-preview{text-align: center; }
   .icam-page-prodotti-preview > img{display: inline-block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; }
   .icam-cta-section{display: none}
   .icam-form-contatti{display:none}
   .icam-case-prod-case-studies-prod{display: none}
   .icam-product-case-studies{display:none}
   .icam-btn-red{display:none}
   img{width: 10%; height: auto}
   h4, h5, a{display:none}
}
```

Comment: What are these "difficulties", and what do you want to happen?

Comment: The image properties doesn't applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **!important** if you want to override inline CSS :

```
img{width: 10%!important; height: auto}
```

Comment: Better yet... don't have inline styles.

Comment: I agree with you, if he has the possibility to remove inline style, this is a better solution.

Comment: Cool ! I didn't know that !important override inline style ! Thank you so much !!